# Firebird database dynamic libraries troubles

Tags: windows, qt, dll, firebird2.5

I got some strange problem here. I built some app, Debug and Release, on my pc's it works fine. When I copy it to other PC, without any development stuff there's is the problem appears:

My application should open some firebird database files `.FDB` and get some data from there.

Question is a bit complicated (sorry, my english is bad), but I try to explain it

**On my PC**

I got `fbclient.dll` in folders with .exe which been built. And if I remove it from directory where my `.exe` file - appear same error as on other's PC's - it just coulnd't open  `.FDB` file. When `.dll` is on it's place - everything works good.

When I use `Dependency Walker` and open `myapp.exe` - there are nothing about any of Firebird `.dll` files! It's like it not use `fbclient.dll` or even `gds32.dll`  at all, but it's not true i guess!

**On other PCs**

`fbclient.dll` on it's place with `myapp.exe`. But there are no way it could open anydatabase file - app doesn't work! I tried to install `Firebrid 2.5` (on my pc I got the same) but it didn't change anything. And again `Dependency Walker` find no any firbird database `.dll` binded with `myapp.exe`.

I hope you understood the question.

How could I make `myapp.exe` to open `FDB files on other PC's?

P.S.

App been created with `Qt`, if this info could help

**UPD**
I tired this but it didn't helped too(but it helped many other ppl):

copied `sqldrivers` to folder with `myapp.exe` and wrote this in `main.cpp`

```
 QStringList list_path;    
    QDir dir = QDir(app.applicationDirPath()+"./sqldrivers");    
    list_path << dir.absolutePath () << app.libraryPaths ();    
    app.setLibraryPaths( list_path  );
```

Answer (score 0):

To open a Firebird database, you either need to have Firebird server installed and running (which you probably have on your development machine), or you need to use Firebird Embedded, which has a separate DLL (`fbembed.dll` instead of `fbclient.dll`).

Comment: alredy done it. but nothing happend. I even copied `sqldivers` folder form `qt/plugins` to folder with `myapp.exe`

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a 32 bit <> 64 bit mixup?

Comment: Hmm, not sure 100% but I got same environments on all avalible PCs (windows 7 x64 professlional, you know corporate license stuff)

Answer (score 0):

You've got to have `qsqlibase.dll` plugin in the `./sqldrivers` folder and it's got to be built against the appropriate version of `fbclient.dll` (the one that is used on the destination machine) to be able to connect to a database. You can see the `fbclient.dll` dependency if you open the 'qsqlibase.dll` in the dependency walker.

Comment: Well, I downloaded Firebird again, I installed it. THen I downloaded embedded version, copied `fbembeded.dll` into installed Firebird folder and renamed it into `fbclient.dll`. Deleted all `qsqlibase` dlls from qt/plugins/sqldrivers.

Then I rebuilt `ibase.pro`(debug and release ofc) with new firebird stuff and get my `qsqlibase` dlls.

Then I rebuilt my app, ensured that it worked on developers PCs.

But on others PCs it still not working.

Comment: What does `QSqlDatabase::drivers()` return on other PCs? Is the `qsqlibase.dll`'s `fbclient.dll` dependency satisfied on the machines you're trying to deploy to? Is the Qt and Firebird versions same on the development and deployment machines?

Comment: One more thing: You've said that you're putting `fbclient.dll` to your app directory, have you tried to put it to the `./sqldrivers` or `system32`?

Comment: 1) Well, when I open qsqlibase with dependency walker it seems like fbclient binded ok. 
Also deployment machines are whitout any Qt stuff(except some qt dll which I copied into my app debug/release directory). 

Oh, I'll make `QSqlDatabase::drivers()` output right now!

Comment: 2)I tried to put it to `./sqldrivers` but not into system32. But I'll try it now!

Comment: Well `QSqlDatabase::drivers()` is empty on other PCs and when I put fbclient into system32 it doesn't helped

Comment: That's weird. I guess either the `./sqldrivers/qsqlibase.dll` isn't suitable for the deployment platform (x64/x32 mixup, as Mark Rotteveel has mentioned) or it doesn't exist.

Comment: how can I detect is there `x64/x32 mixup`?

Comment: Regarding the mixup - you've just got to build your app and the plugin on the platform you are targeting. Also, you may find useful to try this: `QPluginLoader loader; loader.setFileName("./sqldrivers/qsqlibase.dll"); qDebug() << loader.load(); qDebug() << loader.errorString();`. It will give you more info on why the driver can't be loaded.